# How to remove items from an array when deselecting a row in a UITableView

Tags: swift, uitableview

I'm trying to capture the selected items from a `UITableView` and save them into a new array. The following code creates the new array by adding the items when the rows is tapped, what it doesn't do is remove the items when the rows are deselected.

How can I remove items from the `newFruitList` when a row in a `UITableView` is deselected?

Or better yet, what is the proper way to generate an array of only the selected items in a `UITableView`?

```
 class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate  {

    let fruits = ["Apples", "Oranges", "Grapes", "Watermelon", "Peaches"]

    var newFruitList:[String] = []

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return fruits.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = UITableViewCell()
        cell.textLabel?.text = fruits[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        newFruitList.append(fruits[indexPath.row])
        print("New List: \(newFruitList)")
    }
    @IBAction func makeSelection(_ sender: Any) {
        tableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = true
        tableView.setEditing(true, animated: false)
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can just check whether the *newFruitList* contains the item you want to add by getting index of that item in your list.

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        newFruitList.append(fruits[indexPath.row])
        print("New List: \(newFruitList)")
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let index = newFruitList.index(of: fruits[indexPath.row]) {
            newFruitList.remove(at: index)
        }
        print("New List: \(newFruitList)")
    }
```

Comment: This method doesn't work either, creates the array but deselecting does nothing, you need to deselect and select the rows to make it remove the item. I tried adding the same logic to the `didDeselectRowAt` method but it did work either, no error I just end up with mismatching list. Thanks.

Comment: I didn't notice you allowed multiple selections. Pls check my revised answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty much the same as adding an element when you select a row:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath {
    newFruitList.remove(at: indexPath.row)
    print("New List: \(newFruitList)")
}
```

You just have to use the `didDeselectRowAt` delegate method instead.

#### Update

As mentioned in the comments, this solution does not work since `newFruitList` does not necessarily have all of the original array elements. See [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45292809/7264964) instead.

Comment: It won't work as `indexPath.row` refers to the index of *fruits* not *newFruitList*. There would be a runtime error showing something like "index out of range". Also, `didDeselectRowAt` *is only called if there is an existing selection when the user tries to select a different row*.

Comment: As @Lawliet said I got an error. This method works only if the user selects and deselects in a specific sequence otherwise you get an error. Thank you though.

Comment: @Lawliet Ah I see, I'll try to come up with a better solution